# "happily" emphasis

Tags: emphasis

> "On  and on  he  philosophized,**quite  happily  unaware** of  the  ghee  in  the  leaf  in  his  hand  melting  gradually  and dripping."

In this sentence, what does "happily" emphasize, **philosophized** or **unaware**?

Answer (score 1):

Happily in this case emphasizes unaware. For happily to emphasize philosophized, the comma would need to be moved from its current position after philosophized to after happily.

Answer (score 0):

"Happily" is modifying unaware, though it is not in the sense of elation. Rather, it is in the sense of [blissful ignorance](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=blissful%20ignorance).